# Strongswan: {parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]} and {recieved NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error}

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I am getting the feeling that I have just done somethign very silly on my end but I have no idea what is going on. For context, I have been using wireguard for a bit and am much more knowledgable than this. For a class, I have been told to make a site-to-site ipsec tunnel ebtween two nodes with no instruction. I've been trying to read what I can to understand how this works, and search for people who have had similar problems but I'm getting nowhere fast and am overwhelmed with what I imagine are some pretty obvious errors. I apologize, I don't like being this person

Onto the situation, I have two subnetworks (10.0.53.0/24 and 10.1.53.0/24), each behind their own ubuntu server router configuration. I am using this guide (https://www.xmodulo.com/create-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-tunnel-openswan-linux.html) to set it up.

The /etc/ipsec.conf files look like this. With the only difference between the two being swapped addresses:

```
# SITE B's (SITE A's is just flip flopped on left/right values)
config setup
        plutodebug=all
        plutostderrlog=/var/log/pluto.log
        protostack=netkey
        nat_traversal=yes
        virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
        ## disable opportunistic encryption in Red Hat ##
        oe=off

# connection to DMZ Router
conn demo-connection-debian
        authby=secret
        auto=start
        ## phase 1 ##
        keyexchange=ike
        ## phase 2 ##
        esp=aes256-sha1!
        pfs=yes
        type=tunnel
        left=172.16.2.53
        leftsourceip=172.16.2.53
        leftsubnet=10.1.3.0/24
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute
        right=208.165.192.65 # <-- not the real public ip
        rightsubnet=10.0.3.0/24
```

and this is the output I get when I run different commands on each machine:
SITE A `ipsec status`

```
Security Associations (0 up, 1 connecting):
demo-connection-debian[1]: CONNECTING, 208.165.192.65[%any]...172.16.2.53[%any]
```

SITE B `ipsec status`

```
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none
```

SITE B `ipsec up demo-connection-debian`

```
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 172.16.2.53[500] to 208.165.192.65[500] (936 bytes)
received packet: from 208.165.192.65[500] to 172.16.2.53[500] (36 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
establishing connection 'demo-connection-debian' failed
```

I don't know what these errors mean, in the other posts I see comments to check the logs but I can't find them so either my default installation is putting them somewhere else or the files haven't been created because no logs have been made. Appreciate any and all help.

Comment: As the log message says, the responder didn't like the IKE algorithm proposal. So check the log there (or try different algorithms via `ike` setting). Also note that you have lots of settings configured that are not supported by strongSwan (or are deprecated, but so is the ipsec.conf file in general).

Comment: hmm, okay, I'll do some looking around. Where is this log file you mentioned. Whenever I try looking for where a log file for strongswan should be,  I have nothing on my end.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/config/logging.html).